# Highcharts series out of plotting area while zooming on mobile

Tags: highcharts

I took highcharts example from their demos and changed `zoomType` to xy. Problem is with zooming on mobiles. When I am in process of zooming with pinch, the series goes way out of plotting area (in both directions) but it does snap back in correct area when I release the pinch.

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/91k0lzzxvo?file=/src/Hello.js:2409-2413

fullscreen demo so that it can be opened in mobile phones: https://codesandbox.io/embed/91k0lzzxvo?codemirror=1

[image]

Comment: I encourage using the Highcharts React official wrapper to avoid conflicts like this one in your code. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react

Comment: this is right out of highcharts documents, I am using it in angular with their official angular wrapper but I am facing the same issue. This is just so that people could reproduce the problem.

Comment: But the problem is visible also in the shared demo (not only on the mobile) and I think that it is related to reproducing it in the React without using the wrapper. In the pure JS everything works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7jephros/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel did you try it on mobile with pinch zoom? My point is I took it from their own demo and this has issues, I am using Highcharts in my project which is in Angular that has this issue. Point is if it is reproducible then is there a solution to avoid this?

Comment: The point is that the shared demo is configured wrongly and that's might be a reason for this issue. You mentioned that you face this issue in your Angular project, but the shared demo uses the React environment. How can I help you without the reproduction of this issue?

Comment: Could you please point out what's configured incorrectly?

Comment: The whole config. As I wrote before to use Highcharts properly in the React you need to use the Highcharts React official wrapper and set your config as a state. Once again, here is a link to the wrapper where you can also find some of the demos showing how to implement charts. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react